# Камера в Unity - следовать, но не вращаться

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект, если камера которая следует за ним. Как сделать, чтобы эта камера следовала, но не вращалась за объектом? Вешал Rigidbody на камеру,фризил его вращения - не помогает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самое банальное это просто брать старые координаты и добавлять смещение, сделанное игроком.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player; // тут объект игрока
    private Vector3 offset;  

    void Start () 
    {        
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {        
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

---

плавное движение

```
public Transform target;
public float smooth= 5.0f;
public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 2, -5);
void  Update (){
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, target.position + offset, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
} 

offset - точная позиция камера относительно игрока. Всегда будет висеть сзди и выше на столько-то единиц.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В Hierarchy привязать камеру к объекту
2. В Inspector (камера) добавить компоненты: Distance Joint 2D и Rigibody 2D
3. В Inspector-Distance Joint 2D (камера) привязать объект на Connected Rigid Body
4. В Inspector-Rigibody 2D (камера) установить минимальное значение Mass (0.0001) и включить Constraints-Freeze Rotation Z
5. В Scene отцентровать камеру с объектом

P.s. Это упрощенный вариант без применения скриптов

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант: помести обьект в камеру как дочерний. Но тогда будет проблема если нужно вращать камеру - ведь обьект будет вращатся если вращать камеру.

Как второй вариант: напиши простенький скрипт который запоминает разницу между координатами обьекта и камеры на инициализации и в каждом апдейте просто меняй трансформ.Позишн на данную разницу.