# Синхронизация движения камеры с движением GameObject'a

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется некая область("Карта") на которой раскиданы некие объекта, между объектами находятся несколько объектов точек (индикатор пути, кол-во точек разное). По этому пути передвигается объект ship.
Как можно сделать плавное движение камеры вместе с передвижением объекта ship (Он к моей грусти по только "телепортируется" точкам)

В идеале как сделать плавное перемещение и ship и камеры

Имеется следующий код:

```
StartCoroutine(movement());

public IEnumerator movement()
{

    var cam_top_y = Camera.main.transform.position.y - Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    var cam_bottom_y = Camera.main.transform.position.y + Camera.main.orthographicSize;


    foreach (Transform item in movement.points_active.transform)
    {
        ship.transform.position = item.transform.position;
        break;
    }

    ship.SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.3f);

    movement.points_active.SetActive(true);

    foreach (Transform item in movement.points_active.transform)
    {
        item.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        ship.transform.position = item.position;

        /*if ((cam_top_y > sca.MaxY) && (cam_bottom_y < sca.MinY))
        {
            cam.transform.Translate(0, item.transform.position.y, 0);

        }*/

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Я особо не вникал, но.. это не поможет со следованием камеры? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573270/191482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно не просто менять позицию, а с учетом времени.  Способов это сделать полно. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Вот видео где также "по точкам" реализовано движение.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7DZo4jA3Jo

Про камеру вопрос не понял. Вообще материала по движению объекта и камеры полно.

Comment: Основная моя проблема, это сделать параллельно движение камеры во время движения ship.
Камера должна двигаться от 1 одного объекта (допустим города) к другому (В моем случае только по y координате).

Comment: @Slimper так почему бы не привязать камеру к кораблю и изменять её дельту? как в ссылке, что я дал